# How can I change the messaging on the Sitecore login page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, sitecore

I've got a need to change the default messaging on the Sitecore login page (www.example.com/sitecore/login). It looks like that message comes from the `Sitecore.sitecore.login.Login_LoginError` method in `Sitecore.Client.dll`. However, that method is private, meaning I'm stuck:

- I can't override the method because it's private.
- I can't unsubscribe the handler from the `LoginError` event because the handler is private.
- I can't add my own handler to the event to change the text because I can't guarantee the order in which the handlers are called.

The way I see it, I have two options, neither good:

- Write my own login page class from scratch, using the existing code as closely as possible, but with the members I need exposed.
- Use reflection to find the private handler so I can unsubscribe it from the event.

I don't really want to do either. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need to override this sort of behavior in Sitecore is common. Reflector is your best friend. Find the class in the code-behind for the login page and look it up. In most cases you don't have to actually try to recreate it by cutting and pasting a lot of code. You can just create a new class of the same type that inherits the login class, then just override the one method where the action is happening. When finished, change the .aspx file to reference your new class, which will build into your own assembly instead of the Sitecore .dll.

However, sometimes if you just want to change something cosmetic like an error message (that doesn't truely require any back-end logic), you might be much better served by a one-shot piece of javascript on the page that hides the default error message when it shows up and displays your own custom styled div and message. Do whatever has the fewest moving parts.

Comment: This is what I feared, option 1 from my list. But it works, for sure. I was already looking at the code for the login page from Reflector, and I just didn't like the idea of copying it all if I could avoid it.

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried to tie the login page to a new custom class that inherits from the original LoginPage with minimal pasting from Reflector. No dice. Nearly all the methods are private and the way it is initialized, most of the large class would have to be recreated (which IS doable if absolutely necessary, by the way). Still, I think a overriding the message with some cosmetic javascript is definitely going to be the way to go in this case.

Comment: That is where I started before posting this question and was additionally flummoxed by all the private methods. In this case, I can't use just Javascript because some back-end logic is required.

Comment: This sort of thing sure does seem like a lot of work in Sitecore. You can still tie in some back-end logic with an ajax call. You can have your javascript say, "Display message X in this box", but then it can get X from a call to a custom url you set up. It could pass in the value of the username field to figure out who had the failed login.

Comment: Yeah, that would work. I've already got the other solution working, so I'm going to stick with that, but if I had to do this again, I'd go with the JavaScript route. Thanks!